# following relationships in model methods (django)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm seeking some advice on my specific implementation; I have Invoice and LineItem models defined (below). My Invoice model contains a 'invoice_total' method which sums the line totals of all line items related to the specific invoice, giving me the total invoice cost.

This works, fine. I'm just after some advice on if this is good design, or if there are better ways to achieve this?

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    invoice_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'invoice %s issued on %s' % (self.invoice_number, self.invoice_date)

    def invoice_total(self):
        total = 0
        for each in self.lineitem_set.all():
            total = total + each.line_total()
        return total

class LineItem(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s, QTY %s @ %s' % (self.description, self.quantity, self.unit_price)

    def line_total(self):
        return self.unit_price * self.quantity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is okay to do so. Although it might seem awkward at first to use `Invoice` to calculate the total, instead of `LineItem`, it lets you extend the model in the future in case you decide to add taxes and discounts to the total. You may also want to store the `total` in the `Invoice` class if you do so.

Also, another advice would be to change the `invoice` attribute in `LineItem` to

```
invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, related_name='lineitems')
```

Now, in the `Invoice` class, you can refer to it as `self.lineitems` instead of `self.lineitem_set`. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Good point re: 'related_name'.

If I did want to save the summed total of all the line items into a 'total' field. I'm guessing I could do that in the invoice_total method? Would I just `self.total = total` and then `self.save()`?

Comment: Yes, that is right. And on the line item, you can use the save trigger to update the total on the invoice. You would also need the `total` to be defined as `total = models.something...`

Comment: again, great suggestion on overwriting save.